# MySQL: Using INNER JOIN to update a flag after comparing data

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry if this has been asked before, I have searched and tried several similar solutions, though none quite the same and none worked for me.

I am trying to update a field 'contactable' in TableA (customers), which should be either 0 or 1 depending on whether a customer has opted out of receiving our emails. All values in this field are currently '1'. If they have opted out, their email address will be present in the 'address' field of TableB (unsubscribes). So I am trying to use INNER JOIN to join TableA and TableB (both of which have an 'address' field) and if any the addresses in TableB match those in TableA, set 'contactable' in TableA from '1' to '0'.

Any help would be much appreciated. I gather it should be quite a simple operation, though I am new to SQL.

Comment: Can you include the query which you have already tried?

Comment: Please provide a code example of what you have tried, or have up to the point of wishing to do this.

Comment: Maybe `update tablea set opt = 0 where address in (select address from tableb)` Not really a PHP question though

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following should do what you are asking using `INNER JOIN`.

```
UPDATE customers c
INNER JOIN unsubscribes u ON u.address=c.address
SET c.contactable=0
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I was not using aliases correctly, and now understand.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to do an inner join to do this. Try this

```
UPDATE TableB SET contactable=0 WHERE address IN (SELECT address from TableA WHERE 1);
```

while this doesn't use an inner join, it should do the trick.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want an inner join to do this?

Comment: There are always many ways to solve the same problem this is just one way that is easy to understand.

Comment: While that's true, I fear it points to a *lack* of understanding

Comment: I am sure that we all will bow to your vast experience and knowledge, so please enlighten us as to what understanding is lacking. No-one learns from throw-away comments like this and I am sure we all will be very happy to learn if you are able to expand on your comment.

Comment: thank you both for the input. having both solutions to the same problem does help us newcomers to understand that there is often more than one way to skin a cat.